# How to get ChatBot user Latitude and Longitude using BotFramework

Tags: geolocation, botframework

I am building a chatbot using Microsoft bot framework. I am stuck on how to get latitude and longitude values from "activity".

Is there a way to get latitude and longitude info from "activity"?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268385/how-to-get-users-location-while-chatting-with-bots) exists already here but that does not give an answer to this question.

I have tried [Microsoft..Bot.Builder.Location](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) and that does not give lat and long of the user but helps in getting info from the user and validate it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Which channel will you use?

Comment: Bot frame work emulator and facebook

Comment: Did you find a way to get user's current location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this free REST API to get the Latitude and Longitude of the place, this REST API works on Wi-Fi Traingulation.

[REST API for getting Latitude and Longitude of a place](http://freegeoip.net/json/)

Make a model class corresponding to the output of the REST API used for deserialization:

```
 public class PlaceGeography
        {
            public string ip { get; set; }
            public string country_code { get; set; }
            public string country_name { get; set; }
            public string region_code { get; set; }
            public string region_name { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string zip_code { get; set; }
            public string time_zone { get; set; }
            public float latitude { get; set; }
            public float longitude { get; set; }
            public int metro_code { get; set; }
        }
```

Now, simply make a GET request from your C# code in Bot Framework and get result like this:

```
public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetCoOrdinates()
        {
            string responseJSON = string.Empty;
            PlaceGeography obj = new PlaceGeography();

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string URI = $"http://freegeoip.net/json/";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                using (HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync(URI))
                {
                    if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode) //if HTTP 200 then
                    {
                        responseJSON = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(responseJSON, obj); // Deserialize model class object and get latitude and longitude
                        return msg;
                    }
                    else
                        return msg;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Messenger on mobile, the user can specifically send their location using the built-in functionality. Once they do that, you can receive the values from the incoming message:

```
var location = activity.Entities?.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "Place");

if (location != null)
{
    var latitude = location.Properties["geo"]?["latitude"]?.ToString();
    var longitude = location.Properties["geo"]?["longitude"]?.ToString();
}
```